# Backbone trigger event after custom function possible?

Tags: backbone.js

Excuse my backbone i'm not an expert, Must execute function **Show** absolutely and only after **ResetQuestions**

```
      ResetQuestions:function () {
       //Great Code Here
        }),
```

I tried this:

```
    initialize: function () {
     this.on("Show", this.Show, this);
      },
     ResetQuestions:function () {
       //Great Code Here
           this.trigger("Show");
        }),
```

But that was unsuccessful, does anyone know how i can accomplish this?

Comment: console.log this value before triggering and in initalize and check whether both are same

Comment: show is a function?? and you want to trigger it when ResetQuestions function is called?? is this your requirement?

Comment: Yes **Show** is a function I quess I could of named it better, and I want to trigger **Show** after **ResetQuestions** function @Raj

Comment: @FrozenMonkeyLizard dude just try doing what i asked and comment, i think the problem may be with the scope

Comment: @aktiv-coder do you mean **console.log(this.Show)**?

Comment: nope just conole.log(this) in both initialize and  ResetQuestions functions and check them

Comment: @aktiv-coder  Results : 'child {cid: "view7", options: Object, $el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], el: body#site, context: "search"…}'   **And** 'child {cid: "view7", options: Object, $el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], el: body#site, context: "search"…}'

Comment: @aktiv-coder To be honest I don't see how these logs can influence the order of execution on functions , I am trying to make One function execute after another. what are you hoping to find in the logs?

Comment: there are chances where the context of this is changed,

Comment: check this working jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/5/

Comment: @aktiv-coder I tested it now seems that in this case calling the method directly instead of using a trigger solved the problem, this doesn't really make sense, I guess that the problem does reside somewhere in those logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need of events you can simply call the function from other function

```
 var sampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.ResetQuestions();
        },
        Show: function () {
            alert('i am at show');
        },
        ResetQuestions: function () {
            // Execute all you code atlast call Show function as below.
            this.Show();
        }

    });
var view = new sampleView();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       this.ResetQuestions().promise().done(function() {   // Using promise here. 
         this.Show();
       });
    },
    Show: function(){

    },
    ResetQuestions: function(){
    // Execute all you code atlast call Show function as below.

    }

});
```

Then initiate your view,

```
var view = new sampleView();
```

Hope this works!!

Comment: I tried your code and it behaves the same, I need a way to escape  Asynchronous, the problem is that I need to Execute **Show** absolutely and only after **ResetQuestions** is done

Comment: So use promise api, Which is there in build in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just got confused what runs what and by naming event and method with same name `Show`. I have created a jsfiddle with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/yuraji/aqymbeyy/ - you call ResetQuestion method, it triggers `Show` event, and the `Show` event runs `Show` method.

EDIT: I have updated the fiddle to demonstrate that you probably have to bind the methods to the instance, I used `_.bindAll` for that. If you don't do that you may get event as the context (`this`).

EDIT: Then, if your `ResetQuestions` runs asynchronous code, like an ajax request to get new questions, you will have to make sure that your `Show` event is triggered when the request is completed.